# Is there a single word for watched and watching

Tags: single-word-requests

This word goes with the context of anime I'm watching

i.e These are all the animes that I'm (the word)

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to explain more about what you're looking for. "Watched" and "watching" are just two tenses of the same word. It would probably help to give an example using a full sentence, not just a phrase.

Comment: Have you looked for synonyms of either?

Comment: Yes i've looked for synonyms however I can not find any

Answer (score 1):

[Binge-watching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binge-watching)

> Binge-watching (also called binge-viewing) is the practice of watching entertainment or informational content for a prolonged time span, usually a single television show.
> ...
> Binge-watching as an observed cultural phenomenon has become popular with the rise of video streaming services in the 2006–2007 time frame, such as Netflix, Amazon Prime Video, and Hulu through which the viewer can watch television shows and movies on-demand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to express an action that *started in the past and is continuing*: there are some animes that you have watched and some you haven't (yet). You can do this with the present perfect continuous tense (also known as the present perfect progressive tense). However, it isn't a single word:

> These are all the animes that I've been watching.